# What is a specific example of a Calabi-Yau manifold? are there simple ones like a 6-torus, $T^6=(S^1)^6$ or $S^3\times T^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, compactification, calabi-yau

What is a specific example of a 6D [Calabi-Yau manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold)? are there simple ones like a 6-torus, $T^6=(S^1)^6$ , $S^3\times T^3$, or similar structures with products of Spheres and Torus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6-torus, obtained by identifying the boundaries of a parallelpiped of $\mathbb{R}^6$ (or, more properly, $\mathbb{C}^3$), is a Calabi-Yau manifold.  Note that one characteristic of a Calabi-Yau manifold is that it is Ricci-flat, which may impose restrictions on whether you can have metrics of the form $S^n \times T^n$;  certainly the "naïve" metric on $S^n$ is not Ricci-flat, but as far as I know it is an open question whether there exists a flat metric on $S^n$ for $n \geq 4$.

You may find [this review paper](https://homes.psd.uchicago.edu/%7Esethi/Teaching/P484-W2004/calabi-yau.pdf) useful, though I wrote it as a graduate student almost 20 years ago and there are probably inaccuracies & infelicities.  In addition, there may have been discoveries in the intervening years that are not reflected there.  Caveat lector.

Comment: I am skeptical on whether we can have any physical mapping like "identifying" opposite edges of a parallelopiped, in reality people talk about circles when they are asked how can they identify two opposite edges of a square, but then you can never talk about the space being flat i guess. When you realize the "identification of opposite edges" as a circle, it is introducing some curvature.

Comment: what I believe is that a torus is never flat - please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @EdenZane:  a torus does have to have *extrinsic* curvature if it's embedded in a higher-dimensional Euclidean space.  But it is possible to mathematically define a torus via these sorts of identifications without reference to a higher-dimension space in which it's embedded, and in this case it has no intrinsic curvature (and it's meaningless to talk about extrinsic curvature).  If you want more details on this, I would encourage you to ask it separately (probably over at [Mathematics.SE] rather than here.)